# Implementing Multiple Child routes with named router-outlets

Tags: angular, routes, angular7

I'm trying to implement routes for multiple children but currently the named router-outlet seems to be working only for level-one hierarchy of children. I tried the same approach as for level-one to implement level-two but the routes show a mismatch and navigates by home.

The route module structure

```
  {path: '_root', component: AppComponent},
  {path: 'AfterLoginParent', component: AfterLoginRootComponent,
  children: [
    { path: '_Home', component: AfterLoginHomeComponent, outlet: 'afterRoot'},
    { path: '_MyTeam', component: MyTeamComponent, outlet: 'afterRoot',
    children: [
      { path: '_Players', component: MyTeamPlayersComponent, outlet: 'team'},
      { path: '_Status', component: MyTeamStatusComponent, outlet: 'team'},
    ]},
```

How I implemented level-one hierarchy

```
  this.router.navigate(['/AfterLoginParent', { outlets: { 'afterRoot': ['_MyTeam'] }}]);
```

Then in MyTeamComponent's ngOnInit()

```
 this.router.navigate(['/_MyTeam', { outlets: { 'team': ['_Players'] }}]);
```

But it does not seem to route to this level-two at all.

I'm on Angular 7

Comment: where is your `<router-outlet>` in html ?

Comment: `<router-outlet>` is in App Component , `<router-outlet name='afterRoot'>` is in AfterLoginParent Component and `<router-outlet name='team'>` is in MyTeam Component. Attached [editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f2rsaq) @SunilSingh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't see any case where you need to use `named` `outlet`. You made it unnecessarily complicated. As per your case, you just need to handle the nested routing. Your current configuration require little clean up, rest of things are looking fine.

#### Routes

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '_root', component: AppComponent },
  {
    path: 'AfterLoginParent', component: AfterLoginRootComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '_Home', component: AfterLoginHomeComponent },
      {
        path: '_MyTeam', component: MyTeamComponent, children: [
          { path: '_Players', component: MyTeamPlayersComponent},
          { path: '_Status', component: MyteamStatusComponent},
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

#### Routing

Router link can be done relatively. ex :

```
<a [routerLink]="['_Home']">Home</a>
<a [routerLink]="['_MyTeam']">My Team</a>
```

Your modified demo is here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xyjmve

Comment: Works great :)  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`_MyTeam` is the child route of `AfterLoginParent` so you need to append your parent/child route on  -  `this.router.navigate(['/AfterLoginParent/_MyTeam', { outlets: { 'team': ['_Players'] }}]);`

Now the angular will know the parent and reads the route correctly - everytime when you are calling a child route don't forget to map the route name with it's parent route

Hope this approach will work - please check

Happy coding !!

Comment: I tried as per what you suggested, but it didn't work. I've attached a repo for you to see the same : [repo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f2rsaq) . Is there a work around for this problem ?